# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In laravel i am trying to link to a particular page but it is showing

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Here is my code please help me figure out the mistake
 in my view :

```
{{ link_to_route('deleteFile', 'Delete', [$file->resid]) }}
```

in routes :

```
Route::get('/deleteFile/{$id}',
['as'=>'deleteFile','uses'=>'FilesController@deleteFile']);
```

and in controller :

```
  class FilesController extends Controller{
public function deleteFile($id)
    {

         $file = Resource::find($id);
      Storage::delete(config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$file->filename);
        $file->delete();
        return redirect()->to('/upload');
    }}
```

and this is my model code :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model
{

    protected $table='resource';
    public $fillable=['resname'];
}
```

Comment: On the error page, What is the URL?

Comment: url on error page :    http://localhost:8000/deleteFile/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make mistake on your params. it should `{id}` not `{$id}`

Change

```
 Route::get('/deleteFile/{$id}',
 ['as'=>'deleteFile','uses'=>'FilesController@deleteFile']);
```

to

```
 Route::get('/deleteFile/{id}',
 ['as'=>'deleteFile','uses'=>'FilesController@deleteFile']);
```

Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters

and Laravel 5.3 now support using `name`

```
 Route::get('/deleteFile/{id}','FilesController@deleteFile')->name('deleteFile');
```

Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Comment: Damn, can't believe I didn't spot that out

Comment: got this error corrrected thank u
but got another exception

**QueryException in Connection.php line 769: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'resource.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `resource` where `resource`.`id` = 2 limit 1)
**
my table name is resource and its attributes are:
resid, resname,timestamps

Comment: @NihalGurjar mark as answer if you think my answer is correct and helpful :) another exception open new question (if not related to this one).

Comment: @NihalGurjar you need to set primarykey `resid`  at your model so Laravel can look for `resid` instead of `Id`

Comment: @SSuhat   primary key is set to resid only

Comment: @NihalGurjar have you set it at your model?. Post new question or at least post your model code. so I can look throught it.

Comment: @NihalGurjar You haven't set up what I just comment above. You need to set primarykey `resid` at your model so Laravel will look for `resid` instead of `Id`

Comment: @SSuhat yay it worked thank you soo much, one last thing why do we require to set primary key in model and what to do if  attribute is incremental

Comment: @NihalGurjar bydefault Laravel is read primary key as `id`. If you set your database primarykey with different key you need to set it. By default primary key is `incrementing`.

Comment: @SSuhat, It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you had a ` character in your controller file

```
class FilesController extends Controller{
      public function deleteFile($id)//it was right here 
      {
          $file = Resource::find($id);
          Storage::delete(config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$file->filename);
          $file->delete();
          return redirect()->to('/upload');
      }
}
```

Try this

Comment: character is not there in actual code ,it might had came when i was posting on stackoverflow i am correcting it. Please suggest anything else

Comment: @NihalGurjar have you tried checking if file 2 has already been deleted from your storage folder AND resource table?